# Move Object Between Two Point in X axis

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I tried To Write Code That Make The Object Move Around To Point lets assume 
( 0 , 0 ) and ( 10 , 0 )
this is the Code i Tried To Write , for any suggestion to Development don`t hesitate to comment :) .

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class walk2 : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () { }

    void Update () {
        float move = 1.00f;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + move, transform.position.y);
        }   

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++ ){
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - move, transform.position.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One suggestion for uploading questions to this site: please format your code sanely, there is way too much whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend just doing a single movement per update -

```
private float move = 0.1f;
void Update() {
    if (transform.position.x < 10) {    
        transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + move, transform.position.y);
    } else {
        transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x - move, transform.position.y);  
    }
}
```

That will have the object move 0.1 units on each tick. I believe Unity does about 50 ticks a second. That being said you can also use the [Lerp](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/lerp) method to make a smooth transform between two points.

```
transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(starting_vector, target_vector, Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: +1 I agree. I wouldn't exactly write the code like this, but if Update is called from Unity (blit/refresh) then let is update frame sync like Ben did.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to use `transform.Translate(<vector>)` this is much simpler to use and I suppose more efficient.

So you will have something like this, `transform.Translate(new Vector3(move,0,0));`